# Percentage calculation in Druid

Tags: druid

I have a data in the following format. I am having a hard time doing profit percentage calculation of a particular item or brand w.r.t to all products on a particular day.

```
Date    Item    Brand   Profit
15-08-2019  A   Nike    5
15-08-2019  B   Nike    10
15-08-2019  C   Nike    12
15-08-2019  D   Nike    6
15-08-2019  E   Nike    9
15-08-2019  F   Adidas  4
15-08-2019  G   Adidas  3
15-08-2019  H   Adidas  7
16-08-2019  A   Nike    8
16-08-2019  B   Nike    4
16-08-2019  C   Nike    6
16-08-2019  D   Nike    7
16-08-2019  E   Nike    9
16-08-2019  F   Adidas  5
16-08-2019  G   Adidas  4
16-08-2019  H   Adidas  9
```

- percentage profit of product A on 15th August = profit of A/sum of profits on 15th Aug (5/56).
- percentage profit of Nike on 16th Aug = 34/52.

I need to do this calculation in a single query. 
If we run it in two parts- first query will fetch data with the date and dimension filters and the second query will fetch me the data with only the date filter. Then i will divide these two.
Cannot figure out a way to combine these in just one query and do the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profit percentage calculation of a particular item or brand in your case can be done using filtered [aggregation](http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/aggregations).

For brand 'Nike' following json will work:

```
{
  "queryType": "timeseries",
  "dataSource": <your_datasource>,
  "granularity": "day",
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "type" : "filtered",
      "filter" : {
        "type" : "selector",
        "dimension" : "Brand",
        "value" : "Nike"
      },
      "aggregator" :  {
        "type" : "longSum",
        "name" : "brand_sum",
        "fieldName" : "Profit"
      }
    },
    { "type": "longSum", "name": "total_sum", "fieldName": "Profit" }
  ],
  "postAggregations": [
    { "type": "arithmetic",
      "name": "average_profit",
      "fn": "/",
      "fields": [
        { "type": "fieldAccess", "name": "brand_sum", "fieldName": "brand_sum" },
        { "type": "fieldAccess", "name": "total_sum", "fieldName": "total_sum" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "intervals": [ "15-08-2019/16-08-2019" ]
}
```

It will give average of profit for particular brand (here 'Nike') for all the days (here 15th and 16th.)